# proc_open: Extending file descriptor numbers to enable "status" feedback from a Perl script

Tags: php, perl, proc-open

PHP's [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) manual states:

> The file descriptor numbers are not limited to 0, 1 and 2 - you may specify any valid file descriptor number and it will be passed to the child process. This allows your script to interoperate with other scripts that run as "co-processes". In particular, this is useful for passing passphrases to programs like PGP, GPG and openssl in a more secure manner. It is also useful for reading status information provided by those programs on auxiliary file descriptors.

**What Happens:**  I call a Perl script in a PHP-based web application and pass parameters in the call.  I have no future need to send data to the script.  Through stdout [1] I receive from the Perl script json_encoded data that I use in my PHP application.

**What I would like to add:**  The Perl script is progressing through a website collecting information depending on the parameters passed in it's initial call.  I would like to send back to the PHP application a text string that I could use to display as a sort of Progress Bar.

**How I think I should do it:** I would expect to poll (every 1-2 seconds) the channel that has been setup for that "progression" update.  I would use Javascript / jQuery to write into an html div container for the user to view.  I do not think I should mix the "progress" channel with the more critical "json_encode(data)" channel as I would then need to decipher the stdout stream.  (Is this thought logical, practical?)

**My Main Question:**  How do you *use* additional "file descriptors?"  I would image the *setup* of additional channels to be straightforward, such as the 3 => ... in the below:

```
$tunnels = array(   
   0 => array('pipe', 'r'),     
   1 => array('pipe', 'w'),    
   2 => array('pipe', 'w'),    
   3 => array('pipe', 'w')        
);

$io = array();
$resource = proc_open("perl file/tomy/perl/code.pl $param1 $param2 $param3", $tunnels, $io);

if(!is_resource($resource)) {
    $error = "No Resource";
}

fclose($io[0]);

$perlOutput = stream_get_contents($io[1]);
$output = json_decode($perlOutput);

$errors = stream_get_contents($io[2]);
print "$errors<p>";

fclose($io[1]);
fclose($io[2]);

$result = proc_close($resource);

if($result != 0) {
    echo "you returned a $result result on proc_close";
}
```

But, in the Perl script I simply write to the stdout like:

```
my $json_terms = encode_json(\@terms);
print $json_terms;
```

If my understanding of setting up an additional channel is correct (above, the 3 => ...), then how would I write to it within the Perl script?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to monitor the progress of a hello-world program, where each step is a dot written to the designated file descriptor.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

die "Usage: $0 progress-fd\n" unless @ARGV == 1;

my $fd = shift;
open my $progress, ">&=", $fd or die "$0: dup $fd: $!";

# disable buffering on both handles
for ($progress, *STDOUT) {
  select $_;
  $| = 1;
}

my $output = "Hello, world!\n";

while ($output =~ s/^(.)(.*)\z/$2/s) {
  my $next = $1;
  print $next;
  print $progress ".";
  sleep 1;
}
```

Using bash syntax to open fd 3 on `/tmp/progress` and connect it to the program is

```
$ (exec 3>/tmp/progress; ./hello-world 3)
Hello, world!

$ cat /tmp/progress
..............
```

(It’s more amusing to watch live.)

To also see the dots on your terminal as they emerge, you could open your progress descriptor and effectively [`dup2`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) it onto the standard error—again using bash syntax and more fun in real time.

```
$ (exec 17>/dev/null; exec 17>&2; ./hello-world 17)
H.e.l.l.o.,. .w.o.r.l.d.!.
.
```

You could of course skip the extra step with

```
$ (exec 17>&2; ./hello-world 17)
```

to get the same effect.

If your Perl program dies with an error such as

```
$ ./hello-world 333
./hello-world: dup 333: Bad file descriptor at ./hello-world line 9.
```

then the write end of your pipe on the PHP side probably has its close-on-exec flag set.

Comment: Clever.  I'm not sure what the `$ (exec 17>&2; ./hello-world 17)` does.  But now that I've got the channels between the php and perl script piped, I realize that I am stuck in an asynchronous ajax call to the php script which called the perl script.  I guess I need a WebSocket(?).  I'll mark either yours or @mob response soon.  I appreciate the help from both of you.  Thanks!

Comment: The first part makes fd 17 the same as fd 2 (which is the terminal's standard error), and then we tell hello-world to write progress indicators to fd 17. Because of how we set up the plumbing, the dots show up on the terminal too. mob is swell; give mob the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

You open a new filehandle and dup it to file descriptor 3:

```
open STD3, '>&3';
print STDERR "foo\n";
print STD3   "bar\n";

$ perl script.pl 2> file2 3> file3
$ cat file2
foo
$ cat file3
bar
```

**Edit:** per Greg Bacon's comment, `open STD3, '>&=', 3` or `open STD3, '>&=3'` opens the file descriptor directly, like C's `fdopen` call, avoiding a `dup` call and saving you a file descriptor.

Comment: More direct is `open my $fh, ">&=", 3`.

Comment: mob, with yours and @Greg_Bacon help I've got the php <-> perl communication going on.  Thanks.  But even if I make the pipes hot I still can't write to a div in my web page until the ajax post - which calls the php which proc_opens the perl script - is done.  I'm trying to give status updates on how the perl script is doing.  Is long-polling or a webSocket my two best options?  Thanks for your help!